# How to guarantee a random function hits all elements of image?

Tags: functions, random

Let's say you have a random / non-deterministic function between two countably infinite sets. How do you make sure that the random function f:x-->y 'hits' every element of y? Or make sure the probability of f hitting all of y is 1? What kind of random functions are guaranteed to do this?

Comment: What sort of probability space are you considering for Y?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (and this is not guaranteed):

Let $\pi$ be any probability measure on the countable set $Y$ such that $\pi(y)>0$ for all $y\in Y$.  Pick $f:X\to Y$ by picking each $f(x)$ independently from $Y$ according to $\pi$.  The probability that any particular  $y$ value is not hit by  *any* $x$ is clearly $0$ (think, it is $(1-\pi(y))^\infty$), and the intersection of the events that $y$ *is* hit is the countable intersection of probability $1$ events.

Comment: Thank you! "By picking each () independently from  according to ." What do you mean by this, sorry?

Comment: The algorithm for calculating $f(1)$ is: pick a random $y$ value according to probability law $\pi$.  To calculate $f(2)$, pick another random $y$ value, the same way but independently of the other $f(k)$ picks for $k\ne2$, and so on.

Comment: thanks! Do you know if this is non-deterministically computable? Or a way that is?

Comment: I think you have to be more precise what you mean by "random function" for me to be able to answer this comment.